# Form submit image requires 2 clicks to execute

Tags: java, php, css, forms, submit

I'm attempting to execute a standard opt-in form via submit image. When using a regular submit button, the script executes normally. When using an image as the button, the image requires two clicks to execute initially and then one click thereafter unless the page is reloaded.

I suspect that it may be a conflict between the theme code and the opt-in form code, so I'll link to a live [example](http://prosperityclicks.com/your-perfect-is-possible-prosperity-defined/) where the form, page and source code can be viewed.

The opt-in form fades in after the main content area (after 1-2 seconds of scrolling to the bottom).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Image isn't preferred as a button. It gives unambiguous results!

Comment: better use `<button><img src=""></button>` This will be perfect

Comment: as @BhuvanRikka said. use the img tag within a button tag.

Comment: Using the button tag as instructed above still requires 2 clicks to activate the submit form. Also the button code changes the appearance of the graphic. Any more ideas?

Comment: Can't see an opt-in on your example.

Comment: @Ben, scroll to the bottom of the blog post and the opt-in box will fade in after 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Someone has to be smart enough to know where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can try avoiding your image and put a style for your button instead.

Like this:

```
<button style="background:url('your_image');height:100px;width:100px;"></button>
```

Comment: The problem is, the <button> function is still requiring 2 clicks to fire.